# format_map and **kwargs,what does function do?

Tags: python, function

Example

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def urltemplate(template):
  def opener(**kwargs):
    return urlopen(template.format_map(kwargs))
  return opener


yahoo = urltemplate('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={names}&f={fields}')
for line in yahoo(names='IBM,AAPL,FB,CGG', fields='sl1c1v'):
  print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

As a result we have

```
"IBM",143.14,+0.63,3009520

"AAPL",162.91,+1.44,29516910

"FB",168.05,+0.81,11120986

"CGG",5.46,-0.57,42543
```

Opener takes named arguments,then at the next step I do not understand in which manner format_map maps arguments?Why `format_map` and not `format`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help(str.format_map)

Help on method_descriptor:

format_map(...)
    S.format_map(mapping) -> str

    Return a formatted version of S, using substitutions from mapping.
    The substitutions are identified by braces ('{' and '}').
```

It is like below:

```
>>> 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={names}&f={fields}'.format_map(dict(names='IBM,AAPL,FB,CGG', fields='sl1c1v'))
'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IBM,AAPL,FB,CGG&f=sl1c1v'
```